# Get Path and Query from URI::Generic object

Tags: ruby, uri

I'm trying to understand the `URI::Generic` object. But I can't find how to pull out the path and the query into one united string in the API.

If I have this object:

```
#<URI::Generic /api/trading/model/123456789?api_key=12345>
```

How can I return this:

```
"/api/trading/model/123456789?api_key=12345"
```

Seems like I should be able to call some instance method on but I can't seem to find anything on the `URI` api. Can anyone help with this?

---

**Usage:**

```
def get(path, params)
  uri = URI(path)

  if params.any?
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  end

  # PASS SRTRING INTO REQUEST
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)

  execute_request(request)
end
```

Comment: [Net::HTTP docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) says the call can be initiated without converting it to string. What error are you getting with the above mentioned code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-to_s) method:

```
(irb)> uri
#<URI::Generic /api/trading/model/123456789?api_key=12345>

(irb)> uri.to_s
"/api/trading/model/123456789?api_key=12345"
```

---

<sup>Remember, everything is an Object in ruby and you can always call `#methods` on everything to get a list of all the exported functions of that object.</sup>